# How do I trigger a javascript function if body is clicked after certain seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick, setinterval

I need to trigger a window.open function on the click of body, but only if the click is after few seconds.
EXAMPLE:- if the second click is done immediately, it shouldn't open the window. but after 5 seconds, if the click is made, the window should open.

My code isn't working.

```
<script>
setInterval(myadFunction,5000);
  function myadFunction()
    {
      $("body").click(function () {
         window.open("https://www.google.com");
         });
         }
 </script>
```

This is a wordpress website., and I entered this code before `<body>` tag.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: using setInterval would mean that you add an extra click handler every 5 seconds - anyway, do you see any errors in the browser developer tools console ... for instance that `$` isn't defined?

Comment: am new to javascript.

Comment: yes, you said that - browser developer tools console will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to simulate what you want. In this case "canClick" flag will do the job for you.Reset it back to true after your desired timeout.

```
    var canClick = true;
    $("body").click(function () {
        if (canClick) {
            window.open("https://www.google.com");
            canClick = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                canClick = true
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Let me know if you face any issue with this snippet.

Comment: I have to include this in <script> tags right? within head?. No didn't work.

Comment: I have created a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kishorkunal09/450bc3nh/ . Please check this , if it helps.

Comment: it works, but how do I implement this in wordpress?

Comment: Ok Kunal This worked. I just had to figure out how I put this code in the wordpress, searched some articles. and got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
<button onclick="timeFunction()">Submit</button>
      <script>
         function timeFunction() {
            setTimeout(function(){ window.open("https://www.google.com"); }, 5000);
        }
</script>
```

It consists of this:

```
setTimeout(functionname, milliseconds, arg1, arg2, arg3...)
```

The following are the parameters −

functionname − The function name for the function to be executed.

milliseconds − The number of milliseconds.

arg1, arg2, arg3: These are the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: He did not ask for a delayed `window.open` call on every click!

Comment: My bad. Move the function to <body onload="timeFunction()">

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You should make sure that you are placing the code in the right place. Since it's Wordpress. That bugger really get on my nerves. Try putting it in the active theme.

```
var click_allowed = 0; //global var (you use const if supported)
setTimeout(function(){ click_allowed = 1; },5000);
jQuery('body').click(function(){
    if(click_allowed) window.open("https://www.google.com");
});
```

- `jQuery` has been used instead of `$` for the selectors due to wordpress native jquery limitation.

Comment: I should replace selector with body?

Comment: didn't work. i replaced the jquery(selector) with "jquery($("body") . And I pasted this code in <script> tags inside head of header.php of the active theme.

Comment: NO! as I said earlier `jQuery` is supposed to replace `$`. check my modified answer

Comment: thanks @Ashitaka , I got it.. so now, I just copy paste this inside <script> tags in <head> section. right?

Comment: Although this worked, it invoked clicks immediately after 5 seconds. anyways, thank u @ashitaka

Answer (score 0):

you can use settimeout(function, millisecond)